# matlab gui: define buttons in one function, define callback functions in another, communicate

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I'm trying to build a GUI `main` routine that calls external functions to perform updates such as `create_ui_buttons.m` (to create my user interface buttons) and `create_callback_fns.m` (to create my callback functions). That is, outside of `main`, I want to define my callback functions and buttons in separate files (because the main file is getting long as is) but have `main` call them.

For example, I'd like to define my `go` button:

```
handles.go_button = uicontrol('style','pushbutton', 'Units', 'normalized', ...
'Position',[.1, .1, .1, .1], 'BackgroundColor', [0,1,0], ...
'FontWeight','bold', 'String', 'Go!', 'callback',@go_button_callback);
```

in a file called `create_ui_buttons.m` and have it know to look in another file `create_callback_fns.m` for the `@go_button_callback` reference. Right now, it is not seeing that reference.

---

As perhaps a more clear example, consider the `uicontrol` [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html!) from matlab:

```
function myui
    % Create a figure and axes
    f = figure('Visible','off');
    ax = axes('Units','pixels');
    surf(peaks)

    % Create pop-up menu
    popup = uicontrol('Style', 'popup',...
           'String', {'parula','jet','hsv','hot','cool','gray'},...
           'Position', [20 340 100 50],...
           'Callback', @setmap);    

   % Create push button
    btn = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Clear',...
        'Position', [20 20 50 20],...
        'Callback', 'cla');       

   % Create slider
    sld = uicontrol('Style', 'slider',...
        'Min',1,'Max',50,'Value',41,...
        'Position', [400 20 120 20],...
        'Callback', @surfzlim); 

    % Add a text uicontrol to label the slider.
    txt = uicontrol('Style','text',...
        'Position',[400 45 120 20],...
        'String','Vertical Exaggeration');

    % Make figure visble after adding all components
    f.Visible = 'on';
    % This code uses dot notation to set properties. 
    % Dot notation runs in R2014b and later.
    % For R2014a and earlier: set(f,'Visible','on');

    function setmap(source,event)
        val = source.Value;
        maps = source.String;
        % For R2014a and earlier: 
        % val = get(source,'Value');
        % maps = get(source,'String'); 

        newmap = maps{val};
        colormap(newmap);
    end

    function surfzlim(source,event)
        val = 51 - source.Value;
        % For R2014a and earlier:
        % val = 51 - get(source,'Value');

        zlim(ax,[-val val]);
    end
end
```

How can I define the functions `setmap` and `surfzlim` in another function called `create_callback_fns.m` and how can I define `popup` and `sld` in another function called `create_ui_buttons.m` outside of `main` and have them all communicate?

Comment: You cannot reference local or nested functions externally, so to go this route you'll either need a `*.m` file for every function or look into using an object oriented approach for your GUI. Using an [abstract class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/abstract-classes-and-interfaces.html) with [static methods](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html) that you either inherit or call directly would be a straightforward approach for your callbacks.

Comment: @excaza: Thanks! What do you mean by a `*.m` file for every function? I've created `setmap.m` and `surfzlim.m`, but how do I call those / reference those with function handles / callbacks? I was stuck using `@setmap`...

Comment: If you have `setmap.m` then your Callback is defined as `@setmap`.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm confused about how I tell the callback for `setmap` that it takes `source` and `event` input? What are these inputs and how do I pass them from the main GUI to the callback?

Comment: See: [Callback Definition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html)

Comment: So I have a function `surfzlim.m` which is defined as above and I call it from `myui` with `@(source,event)surfzlim`, but it gives the following error:

"Not enough input arguments...Error while evaluating UIControl Callback."

Comment: `surfzlim` as defined above is expecting 2 inputs, `@(source,event)surfzlim` passes it zero inputs. Defining an anonymous function in terms of `x,y` still requires you to use `x` and `y` in the anonymous function definition if you want them to be passed. `@(source,event)surfzlim(source,event)`  is not the same as `@(source,event)surfzlim`. For graphics objects callbacks the `@(source,event)` declaration isn't really necessary unless you want to add more inputs or ignore those two.

Comment: Still confused about `source` / `event` variables. Where can I read more about them in this context?

Comment: The documentation already linked explains them in this context. What is the confusion?

Comment: So they're just auto params that get passed through whenever the callback is called? Confused about how they're passed I guess

Comment: The documentation states: `Whenever the callback executes as a result of the specific triggering action, MATLAB calls the callback function and passes these two arguments to the function`

Answer (score 1):

You really should go for a class. As Excaza told you. However, there're some things you should respect when working with classes in matlab:

- First, only create handles type classes. It means that your classes should all inherit from handle: *MyInterface < handle*
- Doing this will force you to declare the class itself as the first argument of a class methods. *setmap(scr, evt)* would become *setmap(self, scr, evt)* where self is "myself'
- The handle to use for the method, to define in the callbacks, will then be *@self.setmap*

I worked on an object oriented mask framework and I will soon start working on an interface framework. You WANT to go with classes. Not only it is versatile, abstract, and reusable, but Matlab is also full of special behavior that can be excruciating. Using classes help you to control those behavior, once and for all.

10 years ago I was doing interface using structures of handles, just like you, to interact with the item after its creation. Pain in the ass to maintain. Classes are just so much more simpler, you always have the item using a simple getter.

Here is your example code, converted into a matlab class:

```
classdef myuiClass < handle

    %% Private constants
    properties (Access = private)
        mFigure;
        mAxes;

        mPopup;
        mButton;
        mSlider;
        mText;
    end

    %% Public methods
    methods (Access = public)

        %% Constructor
        function self = myuiClass()
            self.mFigure = figure('Visible', 'off');
            self.mAxes   = axes('Units', 'pixels');
            surf(peaks);

            self.createInterface();

            self.mFigure.Visible = 'on';
        end
    end

    %% Protected methods
    methods (Access = protected)

        %% setmap
        function setmap(~, source, ~)
            val = source.Value;
            maps = source.String;

            newmap = maps{val};
            colormap(newmap);
        end

        %% surfzlim
        function surfzlim(self, source, ~)
            val = 51 - source.Value;

            zlim(self.mAxes, [-val val]);
        end

    end

    %% Private methods
    methods (Access = private)

        %% createInterface
        function createInterface( self )

            self.mPopup = uicontrol('Style', 'popup',...
                'String', {'parula','jet','hsv','hot','cool','gray'},...
                'Position', [20 340 100 50],...
                'Callback', @self.setmap);

            self.mButton = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Clear',...
                'Position', [20 20 50 20],...
                'Callback', 'cla');

            self.mSlider = uicontrol('Style', 'slider',...
                'Min',1,'Max',50,'Value',41,...
                'Position', [400 20 120 20],...
                'Callback', @self.surfzlim);

            self.mText = uicontrol('Style','text',...
                'Position',[400 45 120 20],...
                'String','Vertical Exaggeration');            
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Suppose `surfzlim` is a large function, can I extract it to another file and reference that file in the method definition?

Comment: Yes but I would not do.

If surfzlim is a large function, consider decoupling it in small function. If surfzlim has several responsibilities, create a class or a hierarchy of classes just for it.

Then refer to surfzlim as a class member of your interface class and use it's methods handles the same way.

As a general rule when developping an interface, you should take extreme care into decoupling the system and the graphics and never mix the two of them.

Comment: If this answer suits you may you please accept it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below works for the matlab test case when all files are contained in the same folder.

---

**surfzlim.m:**

```
function surfzlim(source,event,ax)
    val = 51 - source.Value;
    % For R2014a and earlier:
    % val = 51 - get(source,'Value');

    zlim(ax,[-val val]);
end
```

**setmap.m:**

```
function setmap(source,event)
    val = source.Value;
    maps = source.String;
    % For R2014a and earlier: 
    % val = get(source,'Value');
    % maps = get(source,'String'); 

    newmap = maps{val};
    colormap(newmap);
end
```

**main.m**

```
function myui
    % Create a figure and axes
    f = figure('Visible','off');
    ax = axes('Units','pixels');
    surf(peaks)

    % Create pop-up menu
    popup = uicontrol('Style', 'popup',...
           'String', {'parula','jet','hsv','hot','cool','gray'},...
           'Position', [20 340 100 50],...
           'Callback', @setmap);    

   % Create push button
    btn = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Clear',...
        'Position', [20 20 50 20],...
        'Callback', 'cla');       

   % Create slider
    sld = uicontrol('Style', 'slider',...
        'Min',1,'Max',50,'Value',41,...
        'Position', [400 20 120 20],...
        'Callback', {@surfzlim,ax}); 

    % Add a text uicontrol to label the slider.
    txt = uicontrol('Style','text',...
        'Position',[400 45 120 20],...
        'String','Vertical Exaggeration');

    % Make figure visble after adding all components
    f.Visible = 'on';
    % This code uses dot notation to set properties. 
    % Dot notation runs in R2014b and later.
    % For R2014a and earlier: set(f,'Visible','on');

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform as follow :

**file main.m**

```
function main()

    vm = MyFullViewModel();
    %Do whatever you want here
    CreateGUI(vm);
    %Do whatever you want here

end
```

**file CreateGUI.m**

```
function CreateGUI(vm)

    f = figure('Visible','off');
    ax = axes('Units','pixels');
    surf(peaks)

    popup = uicontrol('Style', 'popup',...
           'String', {'parula','jet','hsv','hot','cool','gray'},...
           'Position', [20 340 100 50],...
           'Callback', @(src, evt)vm.setmap(src, evt));    

    btn = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Clear',...
        'Position', [20 20 50 20],...
        'Callback', 'cla');       

    sld = uicontrol('Style', 'slider',...
        'Min',1,'Max',50,'Value',41,...
        'Position', [400 20 120 20],...
        'Callback', @(src, evt)vm.surfzlim(src, evt, ax)); 

    txt = uicontrol('Style','text',...
        'Position',[400 45 120 20],...
        'String','Vertical Exaggeration');

end
```

**file MyFullViewModel.m**

```
function vm = MyFullViewModel()

    vm.setmap = @setmap;
    vm.surfzlim = @surfzlim;

end

function setmap(src, evt)
    val = src.Value;
    maps = src.String;
    newmap = maps{val};
    colormap(newmap);
end

function surfzlim(src, evt, ax)
    val = 51 - src.Value;
    zlim(ax,[-val val]);
end
```

You can easily proceed this way to put all your callbacks in the same file `MyFullViewModel.m`